# Magento 2 admin user role not displaying anything

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, system.xml, magento-2.0.7, acl

I have created a custom module, everything is working fine, but when i take the admin user roles it is displaying nothing.

[image]

My acl.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Contact::contacts">
                    <resource id="Suyati_Scontact::contact_manage" title="Manage Conatcts"/>
                </resource>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Suyati_Scontact::scontact" title="Contacts Section" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

System.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="suyati" translate="label" sortOrder="210">
            <label>Suyati Scontact</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="suyati_scontact" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="120" showInDefault="1"
                 showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Contacts</label>
            <tab>suyati</tab>
            <resource>Suyati_Scontact::scontact</resource>
            <group id="email_template" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>Suyati Contact Options</label>
                <field id="pincode" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Pincode Required?</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>                    
                </field>
                <field id="location" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Location Required?</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>                    
                </field>
                <field id="mobile" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Mobile Number Required?</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>                    
                </field>
                <field id="comment" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Is Comment Required?</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>                    
                </field>

            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just done this and it is working perfectly now

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">                
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Suyati_Scontact::contact_manage" title="Scontacts Section" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the issue was and how this resolved it? It seems above you have the section `<resource>Suyati_Scontact::scontact</resource>` but the resource you create in acl.xml is "Suyati_Scontact::contact_manage". I don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried your code and found an issue. You are trying to extend *"Magento_Contact::contacts"* resource and insert a child resource into it. But actually such a resource doesn't exist. And Magento tries to create this new resource. But it will throw an error as the resource has no *"title"* parameter

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: try adding "title" attribute to the mentioned resource. The line should look like: <resource id="Magento_Contact::contacts" title="Contacts">

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine. Did you upgrade the magento setup after updating the acl.xml. Please run

**bin/magento setup:upgrade**

via command prompt and check if it works.

Comment: I have done this several times, not working

Comment: Did you add id "Magento_Contact::contacts" in etc/adminhtml menu.xml?